# Entity framework nested include

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Suppose I have three entities:

```
public class Kecamatan
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Kota Kota { get; set; }
}


public class Kota
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Propinsi Provinsi { get; set; }
}

public class EkstrakurikulerPembimbing
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    public string Alamat { get; set; }
    public string NoHp { get; set; }
    public virtual Kecamatan Kecamatan { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Ekstrakurikuler Ekstrakurikuler {get; set;}
}
```

When I have `EkstrakurikulerPembimbing` records with `Kecamatan` is null, and I query them like this:

```
_context
    .EkstrakurikulerPembimbing
    .Include(x => x.Kecamatan)
    .Include(x => x.Kecamatan.Kota)
    .Where(x => x.Ekstrakurikuler.Id == someInt)
    .ToList();
```

Ef will generate query like this:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[nama] AS [nama], 
[Extent1].[alamat] AS [alamat], 
[Extent1].[no_hp] AS [no_hp], 
[Extent2].[id] AS [id1], 
[Extent2].[nama] AS [nama1], 
[Extent2].[kota_id] AS [kota_id], 
[Extent3].[id] AS [id2], 
[Extent3].[nama] AS [nama2], 
[Extent3].[provinsi_id] AS [provinsi_id], 
[Extent1].[Ekstrakurikuler_Id] AS [Ekstrakurikuler_Id]
FROM   [dbo].[ekstrakurikuler_pembimbing] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[kecamatan] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[Kecamatan_Id] = [Extent2].[id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[mst_kota] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[kota_id] = [Extent3].[id]
WHERE [Extent1].[Ekstrakurikuler_Id] = @p__linq__0', N'@p__linq__0 int', @p__linq__0 = 1
```

Because of `INNER JOIN` to table `mst_kota` (related with entity `Kota`), no data returned at all.

How to query them to return data even if `Kecamatan` in `EkstrakurikulerPembimbing` is null, and if `Kecamatan` is not null, it will eager loaded?

Comment: You need to turn those `Inner Join`s into `Left Join`s. Look at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397895.aspx), and [DefaultIfEmpty()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/DA-DK/library/bb360179.aspx)

Comment: Because you have `[Required] public virtual Kota Kota { get; set; }` EF "knows" that there will always be a `Kota`. Therefore it will use `Inner Join`. Remove the `[Required]` and it should work.